# Problems with kernel (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I got this message.

A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

I tried to change versions but it didn't help.

Tornado version 6.1

jupyter version 6.4.11